# How to change the display of user account to not include domain in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, configuration, active-directory, sharepoint-2010

Trying to figure out how to display just user name without domain in person-type fields during Data entry. By default it displays the domain/user-account.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a profile associated with the user, it should display the full username.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have observed that it displays domain name when First Name and Last name are not set for the user. Once you set it, it will display "FirstName LastName" instead of "DomainName\LoginName"